# How to validate min, max password length before hashing?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to validate the password field length before it's hashed.

**Model class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserInfo {

   /* other code */

   @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
   @Size(min = 6, message = "Password should have min 6 characters")
   private String password;

   /* other code */    
}
```

Controller file simply calls the service method.

**Service class:**

```
@Component
public class UserInfoServiceImpl implements UserInfoService {

@Autowired
private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

public UserInfo register(UserRegisterRequest request) {

    UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
    user.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(request.getLastName());
    user.setEmail(request.getEmail());
    user.setPhone(request.getPhone());
    // Password hashing
    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(request.getPassword()));
    user.setIsActive(0);
    user.setStatus(1);

    return userInfoRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

I suppose the password is validated after it's hashed in this line:

```
user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(request.getPassword()));
```

**How can I validate this password before hashing and saving?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you refer to Java Bean Validation, use `@Valid` on UserRegisterRequest and perform validation there. Alternatively, obtain a validator instance manually (you can inject it) and perform validation before hashing.

Comment: And (1) booleans are booleans; they don't need an additional `is` in the name (property `active`, getter `isActive`), and (2) "active" is a boolean, not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the input of **any** Spring bean. In order to to this, you use a combination of the @Validated and @Valid annotations, like this:

```
@Component
@Validated
public class UserInfoServiceImpl implements UserInfoService {

@Autowired
private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

public UserInfo register(@Valid UserRegisterRequest request) {

    UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
    user.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(request.getLastName());
    user.setEmail(request.getEmail());
    user.setPhone(request.getPhone());
    // Password hashing
    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(request.getPassword()));
    user.setIsActive(0);
    user.setStatus(1);

    return userInfoRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

If you want a better control, you can validate programmatically:

```
@Component
public class UserInfoServiceImpl implements UserInfoService {

@Autowired
private UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

public UserInfo register(UserRegisterRequest request) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<UserRegisterRequest> violations = validator.validate(input);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
        // Do something on invalid input;
    }
    UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
    user.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(request.getLastName());
    user.setEmail(request.getEmail());
    user.setPhone(request.getPhone());
    // Password hashing
    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(request.getPassword()));
    user.setIsActive(0);
    user.setStatus(1);

    return userInfoRepository.save(user);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, a pre-configured validator instance can be injected like this:

```
@Autowired
Validator validator;
```

---

For these to work, you need `spring-boot-starter-validation` in your Maven/Gradle config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm :) Any idea how to validate unique email? `@Column(unique = true)` isn't working for some reason

Comment: @ObjectManipulator `@Column(unique = true)` is a JPA constraint, not a JavaBean contraint, that's why is not working. I don't see how can this be done at JavaBean level since it refers the uniqueness in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Valid`.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/users")
    ResponseEntity<String> register(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        userService.register(user);
    }

}
```

When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation — Hibernate Validator — and validates the argument.

When the target argument fails to pass the validation, Spring Boot throws a MethodArgumentNotValidException exception.

You can handle and customize message using @ExceptionHandler

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(
  MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
        String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
        String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
        errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
    });
    return errors;
}
```

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation)

Comment: It throws `ConstraintViolationException` and not `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. It's a good way to handle exception but it still doesn't solve the issue - VALIDATE BEFORE HASHING. It seems to hash the encoded password.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator You can change `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)` with `@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)`. You may also add `@Validated` at ServiceImpl class